# Registration in Russia on a 90 days business visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, russia, registration

I want to ask about registration within seven days in each new city in Russia. I know there are a lot of people asking this question before but I really need more data about this. I would love to provide a bit more information about myself than ask for questions.

I’m from Taiwan. I really hope someone who has traveled in Russia more than two weeks could answer my question with your experiences.

So basically next year I am planning to live in Russia 90 days with business visa, and I don’t have friends over there. I basically want to live nearby Couchsurfing, or directly ask people if I could stay with them, because I don’t have that much of money to living hotel or live in hostel  every day.

I was living in Vladivostok Russia for 30 days but when I left customs nothing happened -- customs never checked my registration. On top of that I googled, and a lot of people seemed to have the same situation as me: no one checked their ”within 7 days registration”; on the other hand, there are a bunch of people who are claiming that I must register or otherwise I will have big trouble.

Here are my questions:

1. Since I’m planning to live in different cities by hitchhiking, how can I register ”registration within 7 days stuff?”
2. Has anyone been stopped by police and had their registration checked?
3. Has anyone been traveling on a buiness visa like me as well?
4. How is the process of registration? Is it complicated and time consuming?
5. No one talk about the valid time for the registration; for example, if I was planning to stay in whatever which city for 10 days, but then I stayed for 20 days, do I need to register again? Even though I stay in the same city?

   - Or is it so that with registration in a city, it doesn’t matter how many days you stay? It's just a proof that I’m actually visiting there?

Comment: This **unofficial** page gives a good general overview: https://russiau.com/registration-visa-russia/ which should answer most of you questions.

Answer (score 3):

> Since I’m planning to live in different cities by hitchhiking, how can I register ”registration within 7 days stuff?”

You're supposed to register with the hotel or person(s) you stay with. You cannot register yourself. A Russian entity must register you, whether it be a hotel, apartment owner or friends/family you stay with.

> Has anyone been stopped by police and had their registration checked?

I haven't experienced it but it's entirely possible and could happen. Technically Russian officials are not supposed to check your registration documents, only your passport and visa. Your registration documents are tied to the entity that sent your invitation letter, and they are on the hook for your registration.

> Has anyone been traveling on a business visa like me as well?

Yes, many people travel to Russia on business visas. It's normal.

> How is the process of registration? Is it complicated and time consuming?

It depends on who is registering you. A hotel can do it easily, whereas an Air Bnb or person would need to register you at the post office nearby, which is more time consuming than a hotel who just can stamp your paper. I have registered at hotels (like the Hilton and Kuznetskiy Inn) in Moscow, Hotel Mercure Sochi Centre and have also registered with my wife's family at the post office.

In my experiences, hotels are definitely much faster than if you go down to the post office and stand in the lines. The hotels will usually register you for free (as a service to paying customers), whereas going down to the post office costs a small fee. Every time I check into a Russian hotel, I make them register me and put the paper in my passport, so I know if I get stopped and searched, I can at least prove I tried to follow the rules. A Russian hotel will have their own stamp with their details that they will use on your paper. They simply stamp it and fill out their details and your details. At the hotel it usually takes about 5 minutes, if that long. When my wife took me to the post office, that took about 30 minutes because the postal workers are not the fastest.

> No one talk about the valid time for the registration; for example, if
>   I was planning to stay in whatever which city for 10 days, but then I
>   stayed for 20 days, do I need to register again? Even though I stay in
>   the same city?

No, you do not need to re-register in the same city. The purpose of registration is to see your migration pattern on a per city basis. They want to know what city you intend to be in, at all times.

> Or is it so that with registration in a city, it doesn’t matter how
>   many days you stay? It's just a proof that I’m actually visiting
>   there?

Exactly. Registration is intended per city or town you intend to stay in. If you visit a town or city for the day, you do not need to register. Keep in mind, you have up to 7 days to register in any new city or town you migrate to and stay in.

For instance, if you initially register in Moscow but visit Saint Petersburg for less than 7 days, you only need to register in Moscow. Technically you **should** register in Saint Petersburg, but since you have 7 days to complete it, you technically do not have to.

Also keep in mind the Russian holidays. Whenever I visit Russia, it's during New Years and Christmas (Jan 7th) and these holidays significantly affect the business hours for post office and the business days required for calculation of registration days.

Comment: aussie!! your answer is the best , like it helped me so much, and i believe it will benefit so many freaking people in the future!!!  but like i still have a littlw questions i hope you could help me when you are free?

Comment: 1, im going to stay in hostel and couchsurfing host in russia, im going to travel by hitchhiking, will there be some cities without post office?? so that i cant do it?? also if my host or some hostel ( ive experienced some hostels they dont know what registration is) do you think i could ask any russian residence to help me register??

Comment: 2. will custom check my registration? im sorry but i mean, for example: i went to moscow for 9 days without registration, how can custom know that i have been there longer than 7 days?? or it doesnt matter that i get registered in every cities?? ( because i will be living in russia for 90 days by holding buiness visa, i would probably visit more than 20 cities(small or big))

Comment: 3.3.i know you told me that i do not need to register if i only stay in one city within 7 days, but what if in my travel time(total90 days) in russia, i traveled to 25 cities but every cities stay within 7 days, in this case, do i need to register?? will i encounter problem when passing custom with out registration??

Comment: 4, i will be using couchsurfing app ( platform the most) in russia, may iask you how can i ask my host for helping me to register??   4.2, after i register with them, as you told me, when i still live in the samecities, i dont need to register again right??

Comment: i just really wanna thank you again aussie:))

Comment: @NeverExisbut sorry, I was in Russia for a month and couldnt get on here...to answer your questions...1. There is plenty of post offices in all small towns and cities, shouldn't be a problem. Maybe research those towns/cities and the post office locations. 2. They can check your registration upon exit. When you leave Russia, you will go through passport control area and they can check your registrations at that point.

Comment: @NeverExisbut 3. Technically you wouldn't be required to register in every town/city, but you will need to register if you change "regions". Your best bet is to register once a week, if that's your migration plan.
4. You will need to message the host and ask them to register you. You wont need to register again within the same city.
And no problem, I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please see [Russia visa registration when staying on the move](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141661/russia-visa-registration-when-staying-on-the-move/141692#141692), if you are on the move and have proof of travel such as ticket, the counter is reset every time.

2-3. Unfortunately I have no idea.

4. It is not complicated and time-consuming (I think it would take around half an hour), but it requires an owner of some livable property to register you on their premises. Not all hosts can do this for you if they rent and/or do not want to bother with bureaucracy.
5. Registration has beginning date and end date. Once it ended, you have e.g. 7 days to leave this location or register again, you can theoretically be in trouble after that. I think hotels will register you for the duration of your stay.

Comment: thank you alamar:)) i will listen to your advice and get registered, but like i dont know how to get registration from hostel:(( hotel  know this for sure, but hostel they prolly dont know:(( do you have experience of getting registration in hostel??

Comment: I think that hostels will know their business. I can only guess since I am Russian citizen.

Answer (score 1):

I travelled to Russia on a business visa in 2011 (as a tourist) as it had multiple entry, and a longer time.

I had to register at hotels, although some didn't like doing it, but it's fairly straight-forward.

I was asked once by police to see all my documents. Again though, this is easy to deal with - just keep your tickets/evidence of your accommodation and you can show it 'reset'.  Note that I seem to remember you had to still register at least once a week or something, even if you keep moving.  Frustrating.

Comment: thank you so much mark mayo supports monica:)) you make my worries reduce to 20 percent:)) but like , have you tried getting registered in hostel?? becasue i dont have much budget for living in expensive hotel:((

Comment: also umm, did you register multiple times?? or only once within a city??  thank you !!

Comment: @NeverExisbut best to ask new questions as separate, not in the comments. But yes, I stayed in hostels most of the  time (eg St Petersburg, Moscow) and even camped in Novosibirsk (Campsite registered us).  Only once in a city as I stayed at same accommodation, presumably if you moved after a week to a new hostel, you might need to re-register? Not sure.

Comment: im sorry mark mayo supports monica, i wanna answer and ask you in different place, but just last quetions, okay?/ may i ask did custom ask you question about holding a busines visa but traveling in russia?? because i will be holding business visa but i do nothing with business, did you have trouble for that ?? or what did they check??  i just wanna thank you again, Thank you for being so generous

Comment: @NeverExisbut had no issues at all.  I even wrote a letter from me, for me, saying I was travelling as a tourist. That was accepted.